# Simple Date Format java pattern

Tags: java, date, jakarta-ee

Can any help me for what is SimpleDateFormat for this patter:

```
Sunday 20 September, 2013
```

`SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy") for 20 September, 2013`

what for Sunday?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `EEEE` for "*Sunday*". Have a look at the docs of [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to know about all the patterns available.

In your case, for *"Sunday 20 September, 2013"*

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd MMMM, yyyy"); // This should work.
```

Comment: I think it is `EEE` look http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @user3145373ツ - The OP wants it as Sunday and not Sun. That is why the pattern has to be `EEEE` and not `EEE`.

Comment: Oh yes I have just tried it. Run great, sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

`EEEE` stands for day of week for example `Sunday`.

Comment: It has to be `EEEE` and not `EEE`.

Comment: @R.J : oh sorry for that, have updated.